# Script that calls ausearch behaves differently when piped data on stdin

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Can someone explain why passing a bash script data via STDIN would cause the command within the script to NOT function?

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ausearch -i -a 1221217
```

If I run the following it outputs the ausearch results as expected:

```
./au.sh
```

However, if I do this:

```
echo "blah" | ./au.sh
```

Then it outputs:

```
<no matches>
```

Both execution methods should return the same results(since ausearch is hardcoded) but stdin seems to break it.

I am **NOT** asking about how to read stdin data in a bash script.

Comment: Will it help if you [close stdin](https://superuser.com/questions/813472/how-do-i-close-stdin-in-a-shell-script)? Seems like `ausearch` captures the stdin data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ausearch` changes its behavior if stdin is a pipe. If it is it searches through stdin rather than through the audit daemon logs. You can use `--input-logs` to force it to read from the logs.

```
echo "blah" | ausearch -i -a 1221217 --input-logs
```

Redirecting stdin would achieve the same end.

```
#!/bin/bash
ausearch -i -a 1221217 < /dev/null
```

Comment: Note that this is a great example of why having a program change its behavior depending on whether input is a tty or a pipe is bad practice.  It violates the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with bash, stdin, or your script. ausearch's behavior is the cause.

> The ausearch utility can
>   also take input from stdin as long as the input is the raw log data.

See the ausearch manpage: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ausearch.8.html

Your script is passing the args just as it should but because of the pipe ausearch is only reading "blah" from stdin and not the default logfiles and giving no matches.

If you need this to not happen use SOMEVAR=$(cat /dev/stdin) to capture stdin in bash and pass it to ausearch or any other part of the script as $SOMEVAR.